# Problem with antlr grammar (lexical)

Tags: antlr3

I get a mismatched set exception when I try to parse "abc" (the quote marks are part of the input)

Here is the (simplified) grammar - pretty much verbatim from the Java.g example and basically the same from other example grammars. Is there some bug in the latest version? Using 3.2 in the context of eclipse.

Thanks in advance.

grammar String;

options {
  language = C;
}

rule: literal EOF;

literal
    :   CHARLITERAL
    |   STRINGLITERAL
    ;

CHARLITERAL
    :   '\'' 
        (   EscapeSequence 
        |   ~( '\'' | '\\' | '\r' | '\n' )
        ) 
        '\''
    ;

STRINGLITERAL
    :   '"' 
        (   EscapeSequence
        |   ~( '\\' | '"' | '\r' | '\n' )
        )*
        '"' 
    ;

fragment
EscapeSequence 
    :   '\\' (
                 'b' 
             |   't' 
             |   'n' 
             |   'f' 
             |   'r' 
             |   '\"' 
             |   '\'' 
             |   '\\' 
             |
                 ('0'..'3') ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
             |
                 ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7') 
             |
                 ('0'..'7')
             )
;

Comment: I tried to correct the formatting. I'm not sure if I altered the meaning of some productions, hard time understanding the diffs on this site. Sorry if so.

Comment: I fixed the formatting. The source was correct, but the printing lost the escape char (\\). Should be fixed now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your grammar as is works within ANTLRWorks with a java target.  Are you still getting the exception in C?

Comment: I've never used ANTLRWorks, but I'll try it. I am getting it in C, but I tried Java also and got the same exception. I you using 3.2 with ANTLRWorks as well.

Comment: I get the same result on ANTLRWorks but with some additional info (which I can't interpret!)[08:37:39] Interpreting...
[08:37:39] problem matching token at 1:2 MismatchedTokenException(97!=34)
[08:37:39] problem matching token at 1:3 NoViableAltException('b'@[1:1: Tokens : ( CHARLITERAL | STRINGLITERAL );])
[08:37:39] problem matching token at 1:4 NoViableAltException('c'@[1:1: Tokens : ( CHARLITERAL | STRINGLITERAL );])
[08:37:39] problem matching token at 1:5 NoViableAltException(''@[()* loopback of 20:13: ( EscapeSequence | ~ ( '\\' | '"' | '\r' | '\n' ) )*])

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused by these last edits, but the problem is with the interpreter and is a known problem. Reported in 09.

If the code is generated for the grammar, it works like a charm.

It seems hard to believe that this bug has gone unanswered so long given it's frequency of occurrence.